# Multiplicative subsets of $\mathbb{Z}$ for which $S^{-1} \mathbb{Z}$ is $\mathbb{Q}$

Tags: ring-theory, field-theory, localization

In Hungerford’s Algebra, there is a problem which asks for conditions on $S$, a multiplicative subset of $\mathbb{Z}$, which ensure an isomorphism between $\mathbb{Q}$ and $S^{-1} \mathbb{Z}$.

Examples of multiplicative subsets which yield the result are $n \mathbb{Z}$ for $n > 1$ and an example of a multiplicative subset which does not yield the rationals is $\{ 2^k | k \in \mathbb{N} \}$. The multiplicative subsets just mentioned are relatively simple though and so I’m not exactly sure what condition(s) on $S$ would be vital in this context.

$S^{-1} \mathbb{Z}$ is the smallest commutative ring for which each element of $S$ is a unit and so there must be a copy of this ring within $\mathbb{Q}$ and if $S^{-1} \mathbb{Z}$ is a field then it must contain a copy of $\mathbb{Q}$. So, would it be enough to find a condition on $S$ so that $S^{-1} \mathbb{Z}$? More so, what is such a condition?

Comment: Hint:  all primes must be invertible, and $n$ is invertible $\iff$ all its (prime) factors are.

Comment: @BillDubuque is that to say then that for each prime $p$, there must exist some $s \in S$ for which $p|s$?

Comment: Yes. more generally call a submonoid $\,M \subseteq \Bbb Z$ *saturated* when $\,ab\in M \iff a,b\in M.\,$ Then it is easy to show that localizing at $S$ is the same as localizing at its saturation (smallest saturated monoid containing $S),\,$ and, further, the complement of a saturated monoid is the union of the prime ideals that don't meet it. So localizations are characterized by the prime ideals that survive.